# Pandas series changed through CSV export import

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to save pandas series and make sure that, once loaded again, they are exactly the same. However, they are not. I tried to manipulate the result in various ways but cannot find a solution. This is my MWE:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range(start='2010', periods=100, freq='1M')

ts = pd.Series(data=range(100), index=idx)

ts.to_csv(f'test.csv')
imported_ts= pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=',', index_col=None)

print(ts.equals(imported_ts))

>>> False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. A pandas Series contains an index and a data column, both having a type (the `dtype`), a (possibly complex) title which itself has a type, and values.

A CSV file is just a text file which contains text representations of values and optionaly the text representation of the title in first row. Nothing more. When things are simple, meaning if the titles are simple strings, and all values are integers or *small decimal* (*), the save-load round trip will give you exactly what you initially had.

But if you have more complex use cases, for example date types, or object dtype columns containing `decimal.Decimal` values, the generated CSV file will only contain a textual representation with no type information. So it is impossible to make sure of the original dtype by reading the content of a csv file, the reason why the `read_csv` method has so many options.

---

(*) by small decimal I mean a small number of digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

what happening is read_csv by default is looking for a dataframe even if it is a single column, in addition due to the lack of csv typing, it could possibly be more difficult then my suggestio. i that case see @Serge Ballesta's answer

if its a simple case, try to convert the result :

```
print(ts.equals(imported_ts.iloc[:,0]))
```

Comment: It returns "False"

Comment: the case is more complicated then... see the most voted answer

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by using `pickle` instead.

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range(start='2010', periods=100, freq='1M')

ts = pd.Series(data=range(100), index=idx)

ts.to_pickle("./test.pkl")

unpickled_df = pd.read_pickle("./test.pkl")

print(ts.equals(unpickled_df))


>>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the dates as index and comparing with the values of your df. Do this instead..

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range(start='2010', periods=100, freq='1M')

ts = pd.Series(data=range(100), index=idx)

ts.to_csv(f'test.csv')
imported_ts= pd.read_csv('test.csv', delimiter=',', index_col=['Unnamed: 0'])

print(ts.index.equals(imported_ts.index))
```

Gives

```
True
```

Comment: print(ts.index.equals(imported_ts.index)) is not the condition. The series exported and imported series should be equal, not their index

Comment: a csv was exported and imported as a df. The asker just wants to see if the data is the same.

Comment: ah alright! you are the asker. glad you found the workaround!